# Why are my if statements acting like the condition is always true?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

Here is my code. My issue is is that the keys are getting "pressed" even though there is nothing jumping any of the pins on the Arduino.

```
// UNO-HIDKeyboard-Library - Version: Latest 
// This program has been created by pcs3rd.
// Please do not change this line.
#include <HIDKeyboard.h>
HIDKeyboard keyboard;   // Initiate keyboard
// Pin deffanitions and variables...
int key0 = 2;   // Button 0 (Unused but optional)
int key1 = 3;   // Button 1
int key2 = 4;   // Button 2
int key3 = 5;   // Button 3
int key4 = 6;   // Button 4
int key5 = 7;   // Button 5
int key6 = 8;   // Button 6
int key7 = 9;   // Button 7
int key8 = 10;  // Button 8
int led0 = 13;  // Indicator light.
int state0 = 0; // Button 0
int state1 = 0; // Button 1
int state2 = 0; // Button 2
int state3 = 0; // Button 3
int state4 = 0; // Button 4
int state5 = 0; // Button 5
int state6 = 0; // Button 6
int state7 = 0; // Button 7
int state8 = 0; // Button 8

void setup() {
   keyboard.begin();    // Start keyboard emulation 
   Serial.begin(9600);  // Start Serial Output
   delay(300);          // Wait to be recognized be PC.
   pinMode(key1, INPUT_PULLUP); // set pin mode
   pinMode(key2, INPUT_PULLUP); // set pin mode
   pinMode(key3, INPUT_PULLUP); // set pin mode
   pinMode(key4, INPUT_PULLUP); // set pin mode
   pinMode(key5, INPUT_PULLUP); // set pin mode
   pinMode(key6, INPUT_PULLUP); // set pin mode
   pinMode(key7, INPUT_PULLUP); // set pin mode
   pinMode(key8, INPUT_PULLUP); // set pin mode
   pinMode(led0, OUTPUT);       // set pin mode
   Serial.println("Startup Completed!");
}


void loop() {
   // write state info to vars
   state0 = digitalRead(key0); // Button 0
   state1 = digitalRead(key1); // Button 1
   state2 = digitalRead(key2); // Button 2
   state3 = digitalRead(key3); // Button 3
   state4 = digitalRead(key4); // Button 4
   state5 = digitalRead(key5); // Button 5
   state6 = digitalRead(key6); // Button 6
   state7 = digitalRead(key7); // Button 7
   state8 = digitalRead(key8); // Button 8
   if (state0 == HIGH) {       // Button 0
     digitalWrite(led0, HIGH);
     // keyboard.pressSpecialKey(0x68); (You can enter a scancode instead of 0x68,)
     Serial.println("state0");
     delay(30);
   }
   if (state1 == HIGH) { // Button 1
     digitalWrite(led0, HIGH);
     keyboard.pressSpecialKey(0x68);
     Serial.println("state1");
     delay(30);
   }
   if (state2 == HIGH) { // Button 2
     digitalWrite(led0, HIGH);
     keyboard.pressSpecialKey(0x69);
     Serial.println("state2");
     delay(30);
   }
   if (state3 == HIGH) { // Button 3
     digitalWrite(led0, HIGH);
     keyboard.pressSpecialKey(0x6A);
     Serial.println("state3");
     delay(30);
   }
   if (state4 == HIGH) { // Button 4
     digitalWrite(led0, HIGH);
     keyboard.pressSpecialKey(0x6B);
     Serial.println("state4");
     delay(30);
   }
   if (state5 == HIGH) { // Button 5
     digitalWrite(led0, HIGH);
     keyboard.pressSpecialKey(0x6C);
     Serial.println("state5");
     delay(30);
   }
   if (state6 == HIGH) { // Button 6
     digitalWrite(led0, HIGH);
     keyboard.pressSpecialKey(0x6D);
     Serial.println("state6");
     delay(30);
   }
   if (state7 == HIGH) { // Button 7
     digitalWrite(led0, HIGH);
     keyboard.pressSpecialKey(0x6E);
     Serial.println("state7");
     delay(30);
   }
   if (state8 == HIGH) { // Button 8
     digitalWrite(led0, HIGH);
     keyboard.pressSpecialKey(0x0F);
     Serial.println("state8");
     delay(30);
   }
   digitalWrite(led0, LOW);
   Serial.println("scan");
   delay(30);
}
```

Yet, even though I have 'if' statements, the code still gets executed, as shown in my monitor:

Startup Completed!

```
state0
hstate1
istate2
jstate3
kstate4
lstate5
mstate6
nstate7
state8
scan
state0
hstate1
istate2
jstate3
kstate4
lstate5
mstate6
nstate7
state8
scan
```

Are there any hints to what could be going on? I reformatted the code for readability, but it is pretty much the same as before. Also, I am not using pin 0 or one. I am using 13 for onboard LED.

Comment: Change `state1 == HIGH` etc. to `state1 == 1`.  Does that solve it?

Comment: @MichaelT ,as I just discovered through serial output, no it doesn't change anything. But I did discover that The code gets stuck at the first statement when I set to chech against HIGH but it racks through all of the statements if i set it LOW

Comment: how did you wire the 'keys'? to 5 V pin?  do you have pull-down resistors? did you really connect some button to pin1? and HID on Uno?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE. You might find this post on our Meta site helpful: [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange).

Comment: The uno is capable of hid, just not at the same time as everything else, take a look at lufa. and I don't have any keys wired, therefore, none of the code in the statements should get executed @Juraj .Also, the question isn't about the code, its about why the code in the if statement is gettingexecuted even though the gpio pin(s) aren't ber\ing jumped to .

Comment: after you edited the question, you still have it wrong: with input_pullup pins are HIGH, if not connected to ground

Answer (score 1):

Microcontroller pins tend to read LOW when left floating (but not always!). However, pin 1 is used to communicate with the USB-UART converter, and I believe it is set HIGH in the idle state. So assuming you are not pressing any buttons, keys 2-8 will be in the LOW state by default, but key 1 will be HIGH. Hence when `defaultCase = HIGH;`, the first `if` is triggered. When `defaultCase = LOW;` all `if`'s but the first one fire up. Solution — don't use digital pin 1 (edit: avoid pin 0 and maybe 13 as well).

Edit: The answer above refers to the original code without the pull-up resistors enabled.

Comment: So i tried shifting all my pins to 2-9 and its still racking though all of the commands

Comment: @pcs3rd: you've tried it with the new version of the code? If so please please take note of Juraj's recent comment. You now have pull-ups enabled, and all the pins should be reading HIGH unless you start pressing buttons (assuming the buttons are connected to ground). Your `if`s should be checking `==LOW` in order to work correctly.

Comment: Oh. thats probably the issue then